# How to verify lambda functions Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to test following method:

```
public void execute(Publisher<T> publisher) throws Exception {
    PublishStrategy<T> publishStrategy = publisher.getPublishStrategy();
    publishStrategy.execute(publisher::executionHandler);
}
```

Following is the Junit code:

```
@Test
public void testExecute() throws Exception {
    PublishStrategy<Event> publishStrategy = Mockito.mock(PublishStrategy.class);
    Publisher<Event> publisher = Mockito.mock(Publisher.class);
    Mockito.when(publisher.getPublishStrategy()).thenReturn(publishStrategy);
    Mockito.doNothing().when(publishStrategy).execute(publisher::executionHandler);
    PublishJob job = new PublishJob(publisher);
    job.execute(publisher);
    Mockito.verify(publishStrategy, Mockito.times(1)).execute(publisher::executionHandler);
}
```

On the verify method call, I am getting following mockito exception:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
publishStrategy.execute(
    com.test.producer.jobs.PublishJobTest$$Lambda$3/1146825051@6f45df59
);
-> at com.test.producer.jobs.PublishJobTest.testExecute(PublishJobTest.java:23)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
publishStrategy.execute(
    com.producer.jobs.PublishJob$$Lambda$2/1525409936@38e79ae3
);
-> at com.producer.jobs.PublishJob.execute(PublishJob.java:30)
```

I don't understand why mockito considers both the lambda's are different?

**Update**
I solved it without using `Mockito`.

Here's the other approach. `Omitted empty overridden methods`:

```
@Test
public void testExecute() throws Exception {
    PublishStrategy<Event> publishStrategy = new PublishStrategy<Event>() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Consumer<List<Event>> handler) {
            Assert.assertNotNull(handler);
        }
    };
    Publisher<Event> publisher = new AbstractPublisher<Event>() {
        @Override
        public void init(PublishStrategy<Event> publishStrategy) {
            this.publishStrategy = publishStrategy;
        }

        @Override
        public void executionHandler(List<IngestEvent> items) {

        }

        @Override
        public PublishStrategy<IngestEvent> getPublishStrategy() {
            return this.publishStrategy;
        }
    };
    publisher.init(publishStrategy);
    PublishJob job = new PublishJob();
    job.execute(publisher);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, two objects aren't equal because they are instances of the same class! Objects are equal because calling *a.equals(b)* returns true!

In your case, that class *PublishJob* probably doesn't override the equals method. So, comparing two lambda instances results in false. And note: I really don't see how you could fix this by adding an equals method.

In other words: when you do `publisher::executionHandler` you create **two** different lambda instances. It doesn't matter that they will both make a call on the same object. You have **two** lambda instances. And they are simply not **equal**. And that Mockito method checks for **equality**.

I think one way how to test this: see if you can get that lambda to be executed. Then verify that the expected call takes place on that object.

Comment: How do I mock the lambda execution? An example will be helpful.

Comment: I am passing the publisher mock to publish job's execute method. Publisher contains executionHandler and the Publisher object is same all across. So why does Mockito consider it as 2 different lambdas?

Comment: @NileshBarai See my updates. I am not suggesting the lambda expression.

Comment: Seems like mockito is not handling the scenario the way we want. 
I tried the same Junit without mockito and its working as expected. See update in the post.

Comment: @NileshBarai Dont put a solution into the question. You can write a self answer, and maybe (just maybe ;-) even go and accept that one. Questions are supposed to be questions, and answers are answers.

Comment: :-) I solved it using an alternate way. The actual question is how to do it using mockito and what you suggested seems correct.